# Finding the expansion of $\sin(a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3})$ on Mathematica

Tags: functions, symbolic

How to find the expansion of $\sin(a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3})$ on Mathematica, using

$$ \sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$$

to the end? I tried `FunctionExpand` command, and it didn't work.

Comment: Use `TrigExpand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TrigExpand` is the right function to use, but you can get the expansion using repeated application on replacement rules:

```
Expand[Sin[a1 + a2 + a3] //. {
   Sin[a_ + b_] :> Sin[a] Cos[b] + Sin[b] Cos[a], 
   Cos[a_ + b_] :> Cos[a] Cos[b] - Sin[a] Sin[b]
}]
```